# Can iOS Retina images have odd dimensions i.e. 28 x 15 px?

Tags: ios, retina-display, image-scaling

We are currently working with a design who is supplying Retina images to us with odd dimensions i.e. 28 x 15 px which I believe is incorrect as when you divide it you get an odd number like 14 x 7.5 px.

This is a rule I have always worked on but the designer is not getting the point and I thought I should double check what the exact rules are.

I've had add look on the web but cannot seem to find any references on this so it would be great to hear what everyone thinks on this matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, but NOT recommend.

For example, if you have an @2x image with 28 x 15px , your normal image will be 14 x 8px.

If you look close into the normal image, the pixels are not aligned well.

It is always recommended to use even number of pixel in dimension.

Comment: This is not true for 3x images right? For instance, 3x images of 225x300 result in 1x images of 75x100 and 2x images of 150x200?

Comment: Yes, not true for 3x version. This answer is written before 3x images are invented.

Comment: Cool, just wanted to verify. Understood that this was written a long time ago. :) Friendly suggestion to update the answer to reflect the existence of 3x images.

Answer (score 1):

The @2x image needs to be exactly twice the width and twice the height of the standard image, or the automatic loading of it won't happen - your app will load and pixel-double the non-Retina image.

The standard image file will as a matter of course be a whole number of pixels wide and high, so you'll need the @2x to be even in its dimensions.

Tell your designer to catch on ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because in Xcode you design your application with classic resolution pictures, and you can't use a float for width or height. So, you will have a one pixel <s>gap</s> difference between your classic and retina design. Maybe the easiest way to solve your problem is to add a transparent line of pixels in your high resolution picture.

Comment: Incorrect. Downsizing an odd-number dimension image will cause dimension to round up. Therefore, instead of appearing gap, images may be overlapped.